# Nested table tag in html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-table

I'm trying to display a child table whenever user clicks on the parent cell. here is my code snippet.it is working only for the first row after that from the second record it is not loading the data in a table. (displaying plain data) any help that would be great. Thanks!

```
<table class="table table-borderless table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th scope="col">student.Id</th>
                .............
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($data as $student)
            <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" id="row{{ $student['id'] }}" data-target=".row{{ $student['id'] }}">
                <td>{{ $student['id'] }}</td>
            </tr>
            @if ($student['subjects'])
              <tr>
               <td colspan="3">
                <table class="table table-sm table-dark collapse row{{ $student['id'] }}">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">subject.Id</th>
                             ..............
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($student['subjects'] as $subject)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$subject['id']}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
            @endif
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: The only allowed child element of a `<tbody>` element is the `<tr>` element (see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tbody-element), so the HTML you'd be generating at the moment would be invalid. Depending on what you're trying to do, you'd move that table into the same `<td>` as the student ID, or add a wrapper `<tr>` where you have the table in your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic table semantics is wrong. To have nested `table`, the child `table`should go inside a `<td>`

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jill</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Jospeh. it is working but I'm getting span lines under parent table rows

Comment: is it because of `border: 1px solid black;` ??

Comment: No I guess it is bcse of this ```<td colspan="3">```

Comment: nope, can you update the post with the code that you are trying please/

Comment: most likely its with styling, but i do not have enough information to debug the code. As far as the main issue is concerned, the above is the solution to fix it. Please post the new issue as a different post.